# Spring boot validation is not working for Spring boot 2.6.7

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have added `spring-boot-starter-validation` in my pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

and my controller looks like below

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("v1/transactions")
@Validated
public class TransactionController {

    private final TransactionService transactionService;

    public TransactionController(final @NonNull TransactionService transactionService) {
        this.transactionService = transactionService;
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Initiate transaction")
    @PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<TransactionResponse<InitiateTransactionResponseDTO>> createTransaction(
            @RequestBody @Valid InitiateTransactionRequestDTO createTransactionRequestDTO,
            @NonNull @RequestHeader("userUuid") String userUuid) {
        TransactionResponse<InitiateTransactionResponseDTO> responseDTO = new TransactionResponse<>();
        InitiateTransactionResponseDTO initiateTransactionResponseDTO = null;
        try {
             initiateTransactionResponseDTO = transactionService.initiateTransaction(createTransactionRequestDTO);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("=================================" + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
        responseDTO.setData(initiateTransactionResponseDTO);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseDTO, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

And finally the `controllerAdvice`

```
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleValidationException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        throw ex

    }
```

The problem I'm facing is weird. If I remove `@Valid` annotation I get the response properly since no validation is being run. As soon as I add `@Valid` annotation I get empty response body with `200` status. There is no exception being thrown.
I tried debugging as well the code never comes to catch section.

Comment: Make sure that your application doesn't declare `@ControllerAdvice` that intercepts Constraint Validation exceptions

Comment: Yes, there is @ControllerAdvice in a diff class. Is there a way to use both?